# DataTables Export all the records from MySQL Table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatable, datatables

Normally if you want to export data in `.csv` format as an example, using `DataTables` the `Grid` with the `records` (which records are retrieved from a `MySQL Table`) should be exported.

I would like to ask although my `Grid` show some records(which I want only to show) how can I retrieve all the records from the Table which flood the Grid with some of them ?

[image]

Comment: Hi, Could you please add some examples or screen shot of your Grid?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-to-a-MySQL-database-Power-Query-8760c647-88b9-409d-b312-6ea8f84a269b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: I have this dataTable 
https://s3.amazonaws.com/ww-static/images/article-45/datatable-fig1-3-hi.png but it shows some of my records which retrieve from MySQL Table(I want to show some of them). I want to export all the records this MySQL table has without touching the grid.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/

The CSV exporter will happily download the entire dataset in the table, not just the visible ones, so in your example it will download all 50 entries, not just the 10 you can see.

If you want to download the contents of a MySQL table in CSV format, you should perhaps consider using [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/)

Comment: xmmm Yeah exactly I have 100 records in mysql table and here I show 50 but I want to download the 100.... ok i ll check it.... for any new please post...